# How do I remove the "plus" icon in folders on Samsung Galaxy S6?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-6, home-screen-folders

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S6 and recently updated to Android 6. Now in every folder on my home screen, I have this "plus" icon

[image]

which is meant to select apps to add to the folder instead of having to drag them in one by one.

How can I remove this? I haven't changed the UI from default.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new default functionality of Samsung firmware on Android 6.0, a.k.a Marshmallow.

If this really bothers you, you can always download one of the 3rd-party [launcher replacement apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=launcher%20replacement&c=apps) and set it as default.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't know what flashing is but I'm pretty sure I haven't touched the stock firmware. What is a go launcher?

Comment: if you havent touch the stock firmware, forget what i said about flashing the phone. Go launcher is an user interface for your phone, you can download it from playstore. for example:samsung has touchwiz which moslty everyone hates, so they use launchers, try it, it may help :)

Comment: It's still got the plus icon.

Answer (score -1):

Rename the folder to "Google" and the plus will disappear. Then you can rename the folder to whatever you like and it won't come back.

Update: turns out this doesn't work anymore after you restart the device.

Comment: If you've realised your answer is wrong, you can delete it yourself. Then other visitors will be able to see this question still lacks an answer.